# Files not updated in war while building with Maven

Tags: java, maven, war

I am trying to update some settings while building the war package.

I added a this maven plugin to run a script before packaging the files.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>update_files</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/update.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The files are updated as expected. However, when I opened the files in the war package, those values are still the same before I run the script.

How could I tell maven to put those updates files into war package?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What kind of files are you trying to update/change? And most important why?

Comment: I am trying to update the application.conf file to switch connection ports.

Comment: Does the script run before or after the packaging happens?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I set the phase as <phase>prepare-package</phase>. I also tried set it as  <phase>compile</phase>. But none of those work.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? The configuration should not be changed for packaging or may be not even packaged ...

Comment: @khmarbaise  a simple java web application to be deployed on tomcat.

Comment: "none of those work." - and that means?   You may want to provide additional information.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried different the phases like <phase>compile</phase>. But it still won't work.

Comment: You need to hook into a phase running before the package step.  Examine the output from maven carefully to see if you do. 

That said it is much easier with a deployment specific module where you just add the files you need as resources.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Could you give me an example? I tried the `compile` phase.